# Save is not working, spree custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, spree

I'm working on my spree rails app, and for some reasons I'm making some custom methods. I've created a new and create methods in the ProductsController, but the last one is not working propperly, it doesn't save the data in my DB and I cant realize why.

This is my controller:

```
module Spree
  class ProductsController < Spree::StoreController
    before_action :load_product, only: :show
    before_action :load_taxon, only: :index

    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_404
    helper 'spree/taxons'

    respond_to :html

    def index
      @searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(include_images: true))
      @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
      @taxonomies = Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children)
    end

    #########################################by_cjdc#############################################################

    def newproduct

      @product = Product.new();

      #render '/spree/home/newproduct'

    end

    def createproduct

      @name = params[:product][:name];
      @description = params[:product][:description];


      @product = Product.new({
                                 :id => 4,
                                 :name => @name,
                                 :description => @description});

      @product.save();

      if @product.save()
        redirect_to "/tutienda", :notice => "El producto ha sido insertado";
      else
        render '/spree/products/newproduct'
      end

    end

    ######################################################################################################

    def show
      @variants = @product.variants_including_master.active(current_currency).includes([:option_values, :images])
      @product_properties = @product.product_properties.includes(:property)
      @taxon = Spree::Taxon.find(params[:taxon_id]) if params[:taxon_id]
    end

    private
    def accurate_title
      if @product
        @product.meta_title.blank? ? @product.name : @product.meta_title
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def load_product
      if try_spree_current_user.try(:has_spree_role?, "admin")
        @products = Product.with_deleted
      else
        @products = Product.active(current_currency)
      end
      @product = @products.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    def load_taxon
      @taxon = Spree::Taxon.find(params[:taxon]) if params[:taxon].present?
    end
  end
end
```

And my methods are newproduct and createproduct. I even tried whitn and abort before @product.save to see whats in the object, and the object have the data but then the DB doesn't get it. (sorry for my bad english).

Comment: Replace `save` to `save!` and fix validation problems.

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine, I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you really don't need **;** after every line, ror doesn't require that.

Another thing if data isn't getting save to DB then you should make sure that is there any validation failing. Now how to check which validation isn't allowing to save. To know that use bang method with save.

```
save -> save!
```

! bang method will throw an exception if any validation is getting failed.
Then just check the error and fix it.